# Easy WP SMTP plugin test email failed

Tags: plugins, smtp

I'm new to the Wordpress world and just installed the `Easy WP SMTP` plugin on the website. At the time of sending the test email, I get an error message. The debug info says,

```
Debug Info
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I added the setting here.

[image]

Anyone know what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to configure Gmail account, you need to fill
Encryption type: SSL
Port: 465
Requires Authentication: Yes

Or you can try https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-bank/. This would help you in authenticating the Gmail account using oAuth.